# Change this regex to include numbers with hyphen

Tags: regex

I have a regex built to exclude all special charecters - /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/
How could I change this regex to exclude special characters except for hyphen so users can enter numbers with dashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add dash in your set:

```
/^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s-]+\s*$/
```

and you can optimize it a bit:

```
/^\s*[A-Za-z\d,\s-]+\s*$/
```

\d - means all *digits*

@MikeM, you're right. done!
Changed back A-z to A-Za-z as @MikeM noticed.

Comment: @MikeM, let me check if so. brb

Comment: @MikeM, no, you're wrong, A-z is quite OK.


$s = '11-31 ABCabcZz##@@@12-93!!;{}02';
echo preg_replace('|[^A-z\d,\s-]|siU','',$s); // outputs 11-31 ABCabcZz12-9302

Comment: Try `/[A-z]/.test('_')`. `A-z` is all characters in the ASCII range from `A` to `z`, so it includes `[`, `^` etc.

Comment: Also, this looks like it is doing the trick ----> /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9!$*\-,\s]+\s*$/ <----- I could be wrong but it seems to be working in search box